# SQL Server - Index defrag runs forever

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am experiencing an issue with my SQL Server Standard version 11.0.6020.0. I first noticed the problem about a month and a half ago. What's happening is that when running my routine maintenance on the server the job runs forever. Here is an example of the command that will execute for days:

```
 ALTER INDEX [IX_NonClustedIndex] ON [Database].[dbo].[Table] REBUILD WITH 
 (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, ONLINE = OFF)
```

Now this statement usually completes in no time at all:

> StartTime = 2018-12-05 02:00:01.057
>
> EndTime = 2018-12-05 02:00:01.673

But for some reason, out of the blue, it began having issues. I have googled this problem to death and the only clue I found was an article somewhere saying the tempdb might be corrupted. So, I stopped the services. Deleted my tempdb's and then restarted the server. Tested the alter index statement and BAM! Done in seconds. Thinking I had the problem solved; I went about my business. The fix lasted approximately 4 weeks before it started all over again. Repeated what I did before thinking that I would get another few weeks out of it and nope. The fix only lasted for days this time.

Any idea what is causing my problem or what I need to investigate? Thanks in advance.

> ** SERVER SETUP **
> This is on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.
> 2 CPU's with 8 cores each.
> 192 GB RAM.
> tempDB has 20 data files each 5 GB in size.

Comment: Download sp_whoisactive and see what is blocking the process.

Comment: @dfundako - there is no one online at the time and no automation runs during the maintenance window.  already walked down that path but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Right, but are there any entires when you run sp_whoisactive or sp_who2? It doesn't need to be a user blocking. It could be a db_startup, a sync issues, etc.

Comment: @dfundako - Okay.  I get what you are saying now.  Will take another look next time it occurs.  Do you think there would be any benefit to seeing if "DBCC FREEPROCCACHE" would clear the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to solve the problem but I am clueless as to what caused the problem in the first place.  I run the following DBCC commands prior to the maintenance step:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE

DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('tempdb')
```

My thoughts are that a cached execution plan was causing the index defrag to overrun.